# Update a column after a check

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with columns `product`, `version`. I added a new column `valid` which is `BOOLEAN` and what I want is to add TRUE to the product with the maximum version and FALSE to the rest. For example:

**Before**

```
product1 - 1
product1 - 2
product1 - 3
```

**After**

```
product1 - 1 - 0
product1 - 2 - 0 
product1 - 3 - 1
```

I can do this with prepared statements with java but I would prefer add the column from the SQLite console. Can I do this with SQLite?

Comment: You can just execute the same SQL statement. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: With `PreparedStatement` I will store all the records to an ArrayList<myObject>, then find the max version with loop and etc and then insert them back to a new table or update the existed. Instead of doing all this with java, can I do it with SQLite?

Comment: Does this table habe some column that uniquely identifies a row?

Comment: Yes the combination of product and version `PRIMARY KEY ("product", "version")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get `1` in exactly those rows where no other row with the same product and a larger version exists:

```
UPDATE MyLittleTable
SET valid = NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM MyLittleTable AS T2
                        WHERE T2.product = MyLittleTable.product
                          AND T2.version > MyLittleTable.version);
```